# Searching semicolon separated strings in mysql db with flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

At the moment I am stuck with the following and I hope someone can give me a suggestion on my following problem.

I have a mysql db with rows such as:

```
id tags              set_id
1  ;tag1;tag3;tag11;  5
2  ;tag20;tag3;tag1;  6
```

With flask-sqlalchemy, I try to search these rows based a list of tags and a set id. If a row has the combination of tags or any of the single tags, it is important to me. I tried the following query:

```
    def get_by_tags_and_setid(cls, set_id, tags):
        query = cls.query.filter(cls.set_id == set_id, and_(cls.tags.like('%' + ';' + a_tag + ';' + '%') for a_tag in tags).all()
        return query
```

This however, often returns nothing when I can clearly see rows containing any of the provided tags.

Comment: have you tried using contains() query?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but sadly contains still provides me with no results. One of the tags in the list is tag3, and there are multiple rows with just tag 3, but I am not getting them.

Comment: as a sanity check have you double-checked what `cls.query.filter(cls.set_id == set_id)` looks like?

Comment: Yes this just provides me with everything belonging to that id